# Entity Framework and Changing Views?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a client who had given us some code written in VB6 and is to be converted to .Net 4.0. Theirt database is, what can only be called, a catastrophy. But, we're not allowed to change it. So we're building an application on top of this shakey database.

One thing they did was (Wait for it), create views based on a users selection of which columns should be displayed in a grid.

Example, the Contacts screen lists all the contacts. They have a screen which reads the database, gets the fields from a View, and then presents the user with a list of possible columns. The user then selects a few (Surname, Firstname, DOB).

The code then goes and creates a NEW view (or overwrites an existing one) with

> 'SELECT Surname, Firstname, DOB' from AnotherView WHERE ID=:ID'

(AnotherView is a large view containing joins etc...)

It then uses that view everytime the screen is viewed.

So, the view changes.

We're using Entity Framework. Is it possible to handle dynamic views? We use Linq in the presentation (I know, I know....) to mine the data. So can we somehow use Linq to select * from the view, and then present the grid? If the view is changing, though, we need to regenerate the EF model, no?

Comment: If the underlying data sources have changed, then yes, update the E.F Model.

Comment: Can this be done via code, for just that View (ef) object?

Comment: Why not just display based on AnotherView and ignore the changing one, and filter the data based on what the user specified?

Comment: If it's MVC, I believe you can update it via code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: Don't use EF for these queries. EF model is created in design time and changing it at runtime means so many problems that it doesn't worth it. Use EF to execute your dynamic SQLs directly.